# How to keep absolute child element on parent element that uses clip-path property?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have created the chevron navigation bar on the bottom of page with the help of clip-path. On the top of navigation button have to keep circular div element. Because of clip-path properties not able to show whole div element. I tried with `overflow: visible` property in parent class.

My problem you can see in this image:

[image]

```css
.bottom-nav-section {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.bottom-nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.clip1 {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 33.3%;
  margin: left:20px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #1c7aa2;
  outline: none;
  border: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 87% 0, 100% 50%, 86% 100%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 87% 0, 100% 50%, 86% 100%, 0% 100%);
}

.clip2 {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-left: -25px;
  margin-right: -25px;
  width: 33.3%;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #1c7aa2;
  outline: none;
  border: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(86% 0, 100% 50%, 86% 100%, 0% 100%, 13% 48%, 0% 0%);
  clip-path: polygon(86% 0, 100% 50%, 86% 100%, 0% 100%, 13% 48%, 0% 0%);
}

.clip3 {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 33.3%;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #1c7aa2;
  outline: none;
  border: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: visible !important;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 50%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%, 13% 48%, 0% 0%);
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 50%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%, 13% 48%, 0% 0%);
}

.clip-btn1 {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  left: 40px;
  top: -22px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: #1c7aa2;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  z-index: 999 !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 bottom-nav-section">
    <div class="logo-unit">
      <div class="bottom-nav">
        <button class="clip1"><h5>text1</h5>
          <div class="clip-btn1"><h5>1</h5></div>
        </button>
        <button class="clip2"><h5>text2</h5>
          <div class="clip-btn1"><h5>2</h5></div>
        </button>
        <button class="clip3"><h5>text3</h5>
          <div class="clip-btn1"><h5>3</h5></div>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use `top: 16px` for `.clip-btn1`.

Comment: Not sure that clipping works in all browsers - I have this version of a chevron that is more browser freindly: https://jsfiddle.net/zg3ubLbc/

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try below code - noticed I changed `position`, `left`, `top`. you can change left and top position as per wherever you want bubble to me

```
.clip-btn1 {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  left: 11px;
  top: -66px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: #1c7aa2;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  z-index: 999 !important;
}
```

Please do let me know, if it helps

Comment: This problem solved adding the new div as a parent div. I have added 3 div of size 33.3% for each box. Clip-path does not allow anything around it. But outer div allowed to keep the bubble on the top of it. :)

Comment: Looks like you still have some issues with it, can you please post a fiddle, so that I can have a look